# Containers started through Portainer exit after ~20 minutes

Tags: docker, nas, portainer

I'm new to Portainer, and I can't find the answer of my current problem online:
I started some containers through portainer than are running fine. When I stop browsing the portainer web interface for more than ~15 minutes, it exits and kills all the started containers. Is this a setting that I forgot somewhere?
Thanks.

[Example with only portainer started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjXOL.png)

In this example, I simply closed my web browser from which I was using portainer.

Comment: Can you provide the log of the killed container ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/icF4fCYd  There is quite a lot, and I don't see any useful information